# How can I parse a DataFrame column where each row contains a Dict, into independent DataFrame columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following DataFrame:

```
    TradeDictionary
0   {'id': '545', 'instrument': 'EUR_USD', 'price'...
1   {'id': '539', 'instrument': 'GBP_USD', 'price'...
2   {'id': '535', 'instrument': 'EUR_USD', 'price'...
3   {'id': '529', 'instrument': 'EUR_USD', 'price'...
4   {'id': '523', 'instrument': 'EUR_USD', 'price'...
5   {'id': '501', 'instrument': 'EUR_USD', 'price'...
6   {'id': '495', 'instrument': 'GBP_USD', 'price'...
7   {'id': '489', 'instrument': 'EUR_USD', 'price'...
8   {'id': '483', 'instrument': 'EUR_USD', 'price'...
9   {'id': '477', 'instrument': 'EUR_USD', 'price'...
10  {'id': '471', 'instrument': 'GBP_USD', 'price'...
```

However I need to convert it into separate columns in a DataFrame. I've tried numerous suggestions in other posts but doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: Did you try iterating, parsing, and concatenating?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.Series` in `df.apply`:

```
In [1426]: df = pd.DataFrame({'TradeDictionary':[{'id': '545', 'instrument': 'EUR_USD', 'price':100}, {'id': '539', 'instrument': 'GBP_USD', 'price':200}, {'id': '535', 'instrument': 'EUR_USD', 'price':50}]})

In [1427]: df
Out[1427]: 
                                     TradeDictionary
0  {'id': '545', 'instrument': 'EUR_USD', 'price'...
1  {'id': '539', 'instrument': 'GBP_USD', 'price'...
2  {'id': '535', 'instrument': 'EUR_USD', 'price'...

In [1429]: df1 = df.TradeDictionary.apply(pd.Series)

In [1430]: df1
Out[1430]: 
    id instrument  price
0  545    EUR_USD    100
1  539    GBP_USD    200
2  535    EUR_USD     50
```

**OR for better performance**, use `pd.json_normalize`:

```
In [1432]: df1 = pd.json_normalize(df.TradeDictionary)
```

Comment: This is one of the methods i tried however it returns the exact same DataFrame with a 0 instead of TradeDictionary title. The dtype of the column is Object.

Comment: It will always return the dataframe with name of the `key` as column name. it will never return `TradeDictionary` as column name in new dataframe.

Comment: Yeah I understand that but the DataFrame is just staying as a single column with the dictionary string within it.

Comment: Maybe because `TradeDictionary` column is not a proper `dict` in your `df`. Check the sample `df` that I've created. Run the code on it.

Comment: Am I able to covert the singular column into dict type and then run the code above?

Comment: Looked into the source of the dict and the API I'm using is highly nested, I've took the info out that is irrelevant and now the code above works as expected :)

Comment: Great. Happy to help.